# WPF: TreeView height

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

I'm using a `TreeView` in WPF that has an explicit height set. The vertical scrollbar is cut off at the bottom (independent of whether items are bound/shown or not; I've enabled the scrollbar to be able to reproduce the problem without items attached). XAML source below.

```html
<Window x:Class="demo.TreeViewProblem"
 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
 Title="..."
    ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip"
 SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
 
 <Grid>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
   <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <RowDefinition />
   <RowDefinition />
   <RowDefinition />
   <RowDefinition />
   <RowDefinition />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>

  <TextBlock
   Grid.Column="0"
   Grid.Row="0"
   Margin="5,10,5,5"
   Text="Some label"/>

  <TextBlock
   Grid.Column="1"
   Grid.Row="0"
   Margin="5,10,5,5"
   Text="Some value"/>

  <TreeView
   ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
   Grid.Column="1"
   Grid.Row="1"
   Height="200"
   MinHeight="200"
   Width="300"
   Margin="5,10,5,5"
   VerticalAlignment="Top" />

  <TextBlock
   Grid.Column="0"
   Grid.Row="2"
   Margin="5,10,5,5"
   Text="Some label"/>

  <TextBox
   Grid.Column="1"
   Grid.Row="2"
   Width="80"
   Margin="5,10,5,5"
   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
   Text="Some value"/>
  
  <TextBlock
   Grid.Column="0"
   Grid.Row="3"
   Margin="5,10,5,5"
   Text="Some label"/>

  <TextBox
   Grid.Column="1"
   Grid.Row="3"
   Width="80"
   Margin="5,10,5,5"
   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
   Text="Some value"/>
  
  <Button
   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
   Margin="10,10,10,10"
   Content="Close"
   Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
   Grid.Column="0"
   Grid.Row="4"/>

 </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Your `Grid` rows equally divide available space and you set fixed `Height` against `TreeView`. Remove `Height` and `MinHeight` restriction and set `VerticalAlignment` to Strech (or remove it as well)

Answer (score 1):

Change the RowDefinition for the row containing your TreeView to this:

```
<RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
```

When set to "Auto", the row will calculate how much space it needs.

EDIT: Alternatively, you could set the *other* rows to Auto and then make your TreeView stretch instead.  With this approach your window will scale nicer when the user resizes it.

From the row definitions:

```
<RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
<RowDefinition Height="*" />
<RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
<RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
```

From the tree:

```
<TreeView VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
    ... />
```